# solr not tokenizing protected words

Tags: solr, lucene, tokenize, protected, words

I have documents in Solr/Lucene (3.x) with a special copy field facet_headline in order to have an unstemmed field for faceting.

Sometimes 2 ore more words are belong together, and this should be handled/counted as one word, for example "kim jong il".

So the headline "Saturday: kim jong il had died" should be split into:

`Saturday` `kim jong il` `had` `died`

For this reason I decided to use protected words (protwords), where I add `kim jong il`.
The `schema.xml` looks like this.

```
   <fieldType name="facet_headline" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer>
           <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\?|\!|\.|\:|\;|\,|\&quot;|\(|\)|\\|\+|\*|&lt;|&gt;|([0-31]+\.)" />
           <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="0" 
                   protected="protwords.txt" />
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
           ignoreCase="true"
           words="stopwords.txt"
           enablePositionIncrements="true"
           />
        </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

Using the solr analysis it looks like that doesn't work!
The string is still split into 6 words. It looks like the protword.txt is not used, but if the headline ONLY contains the name: `kim jong il` everything works fine, the terms aren't split.

Is there a way to reach my goal: not to split specific words/word groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching the web a came to the point, that it's not possible to reach the goal.
It looks like, this is not the focus of all the tokenizer and filters.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think it's happening.

`WordDelimiterFilterFactory` is a token filter, so its job is to add, remove or change already generated tokens, (in this case, to split words into sub-words based on case transitions, hyphens, etc.), *not* to split documents into words, which is a job for the tokenizer (in this case, `PatternTokenizerFactory`). It seems that your tokenizer is missing a `\s`, so it's not splitting words and `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` is getting whole phrases.

In your example, `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` would be getting the whole phrase `Saturday kim jong il had died` and, as it doesn't match any of your protected words, it proceeds to split this "word" into sub-words (a whitespace is a non-alpanumeric character, so the word qualifies for splitting).

So here's a possible solution. Add a `\s` to your tokenizer pattern and then use [KeywordMarkerFilterFactory](https://builds.apache.org/view/G-L/view/Lucene/job/Solr-trunk/javadoc/org/apache/solr/analysis/KeywordMarkerFilterFactory.html) to protect your words. Something like this:

```
<fieldType name="facet_headline" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s|\?|\!|\.|\:|\;|\,|\&quot;|\(|\)|\\|\+|\*|&lt;|&gt;|([0-31]+\.)" />
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"
            ignoreCase="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnNumerics="0" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
           ignoreCase="true"
           words="stopwords.txt"
           enablePositionIncrements="true"
           />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Update**: OK, now that I double checked the documentation, this proposed solution is not likely going to work for you. I would focus on experimenting with [SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory). Check [this message](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Index-amp-search-questions-special-cases-td474389.html#a474393) in the solr-user mailing list. It's a bit outdated, but gives some insight into the problem.

Comment: I removed the `\s` from the `PatternTokenizerFactory` in hope, the `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` will split the document on spaces exapt the protwords. But after i read your analyses - i think, i understood the problem. so i will try your modification. just a minute.

Comment: Forget about my "solution", it most probably won't work. I misunderstood how `KeywordMarkerFilterFactory`; it would only protect your words from subsequent stemming. I'll update my answer.

Comment: >Forget about my "solution"< i see - the `PatternTokenizerFactory` will split the term before any protwords will be processed. Right, `KeywordMarkerFilterFactory` is relevant for stemming

Comment: probably i could define an synonym, like kim_jong_il (i never thought, that one day i will write this name so much)... like kim_jong_il is synonym for `kim jong il` but the problem is: synonymfilter will run after tokenizer. So at this time this are several terms: `kim``jong` `il`